# Unfamiliar notation in an AoPS paper

Tags: notation, multisets

Here it is, from [this paper](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/polyominoes.pdf?):

> **Proposition 5.1.1.** *The number of skyline polyominoes of area $A$ and width $w$ is $\left(\!\binom{w}{A-W}\!\right) = \binom{A-1}{w-1}$*.

I'm referring to the first expression, not the binomial coefficient.
I think it's a Stirling number of some kind, but I'm not familiar enough with them to be sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s probably a [*multiset coefficient*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets);

$$\left(\!\!\binom{n}k\!\!\right)=\binom{n+k-1}k=\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$$

is the number of multisets of cardinality $k$ that can be chosen from a set of $n$ distinct types of object, and the notation has become moderately standard.